# Jboss with UTC timezone

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, utc

We have setup our server timezone (Windows) UTC (coordinated universal time) , but when we start the JBoss I could see -5 hours from system time in the console as well as in the jboss log. For e.g., system is 0900 HRS jboss log and console shows as 0400 HRS.

Please throw some idea where we should configure in jboss to pickup UTC time.

Rgds
Balaji

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always enforce a timezone using a Java system property during startup, this does not apply to JBoss only:

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC [...]
```

or programatically:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
```

I'm not a JBoss expert, but I guess JBoss provides a way to explicitly set the timezone, e.g. using administration console or configuration script.

Comment: Yes, same i found it in a website. it solved the problem. Thanks for your assitance :)

Comment: Hi Balaji can you please tell us how did you set the time zone in jBoss