# Openshift + Wildfly 8.1 change time zone

Tags: timezone, openshift

I'm running a web application on openshift using Wildfly 8.1 and I would like to change the  default timezone of my application to America/Sao_Paulo (GMT-3).

Today there is 3 hours of difference between my computer and the server running the application. 
My desire is that my computer and the server shares the same date.

Server: Tue Nov 11 14:42:19 EST 2014
My computer: Tue Nov 11 17:43:47 BRST 2014

Comment: All you need to do is call ``TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));`` when your application starts... But if you're using MySQL, it'll depends on what version you're using...

Answer (score 0):

While I got the majority of this answer from [Jboss with UTC timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594849/jboss-with-utc-timezone), it still isn't as simple as try this...

To get this working on OpenShift you would need to change how java is started on your gear by creating an (deploy action hook)[https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html]. This allows you to change how your application is deployed (started), so you should be able to append the solution mentioned in the link above to the "start" command that is executed by the cartridge. For Jboss its https://github.com/Nick-Harvey/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas/bin/control